# How to make nginx pages running on wsl visible on the local area network(lan)?

Tags: lan, nginx, windows-subsystem-for-linux

ah my last piece of the puzzle in creating a great dev environment...

Nginx runs fine on wsl ubuntu 16.04. On the windows machine I can see pages with url localhost or url of any ip address in ifconfig inet addr:

here is my default sites-available

```
server {
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;

root /mnt/d/fs/www;
index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    autoindex on;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

What do I need to do to make nginx pages visible in the lan?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 blocks port 80 ( actually all ports ) for incoming connections by default. So in windows defender firewall / advanced settings /inbound rules / new rule / port / 80 ... gets you there.